# Boost: Unable to build a shared library on x86

Tags: boost, dll, x86, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am having an issue building my shared library for x86.

My Jamfile looks something like this - names changed:

```
import os ;
args = [ modules.peek : ARGV ] ;

local JAVA_HOME = [ os.environ JAVA_HOME ] ;
type = test1 ;

lib $(type)prog
    : : 
        <name>TestChecker
        <search> /path/to/lib/x86/lib
        <search> /path/to/lib/ppc/lib
    : :
        <include> /path/to/inc/
    ;

lib JniApp
    : # sources
        JniApp.cpp
        $(type)prog
    : # requirements
        <define>JNI
        <include>.
        <include>/${JAVA_HOME}/include
        <include>/${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux
        <library>/test.app//app_lib/<link>static
        <library>/test.app//app2_lib/<link>static
    : # default-build
    : # usage-requirements
    ;
```

When I build the above library (JniApp) for ppc, then everything is fine. However, when I try to build for x86, keeping it a shared library doesn't work. I have to add static and everything will be fine, a static library will be created. However, I need a shared library. The error that shows when I build x86 is the following:

```
/path/to/lib/x86/lib/libTestChecker.a(Exceptions.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/path/to/lib/x86/lib/libTestChecker.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The "TestChecker.a" library is preexisting and not created by me. I am just using it to create my JniApp library. I am unsure as to why this error is happening but only for x86, and only for a shared library. I also added the -fPIC flag into the b2 command but the same error shows up. Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libTestChecker.a` is not built in a PIC-compatible way; you can't link it into a shared library.  **You need to rebuild *it* from source with `-fPIC`**.

There's other no practical way to fix this; it uses 32-bit absolute relocations for some symbol addresses (`R_X86_64_32`) and there's simply no support for that in the GNU/Linux x86-64 dynamic linker.

---

Without source, your options include crazy stuff like disassembling the library, manually modifying the asm to use 7-byte `lea rdi, [RIP + symbol]` instead of 5-byte `mov edi, OFFSET symbol` (GAS Intel syntax), then re-assemble.

Or for indexing static arrays, you might need to find a spare register to LEA into to replace instructions like `mov eax, [array + rdx*4]`.

TL:D:R: if you aren't an expert at x86-64 asm, you need source or to not use this static library.